# GoDaddy : does it come with warranty of not losing my data?

Tags: web-hosting, godaddy, backups

I have a GoDaddy Web Hosting Linux Ultimate, and I'm unsure about the following : can GoDaddy loose my data?

To be more precise : lets say that their harddrive fails, is it my responsability to backup everything OUTSIDE of their servers, or do they provide raid 1 or any warranty they won't loose anything?

(Of course, I do already backup outside)

Comment: This shouldn't even be a question. You should *always* have a backup of your site and data. But the odds are basic hosting does not. I f you want RAIDed hard drives you need a dedicated box.

Comment: As well, I am sure that GoDaddy does provide some language on guarantees and sureties based upon the level of service you sign-up for. You would have to go to GoDaddy's website and look-up the terms of service agreement and read it.

Comment: It's always wise to read the terms and conditions before committing to a service purchase... just saying...

Comment: You get what you pay for, look in their TOS to see if data backup and restoration is something you pay for in your current service level, increment the service plan till you get what you want or provide your own disaster recovery plan.

Comment: I've already looked at TOS, but I find it hard to understand. I know they offer a backup service, but I tought it was to assure me against my own mistakes, not theirs. I first thought that it would be natural for them to make sure they can't loose any data, but Kristi's answer seems to tell the contrary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've known several people who lost their entire websites because they didn't back them up on their own and GoDaddy somehow lost the files on their end. With hosts like that, always find a way to back it up yourself. If you have a WordPress website, I'd suggest VaultPress. It's by the same company that makes WordPress and makes sure you have an offsite daily backup.